# Escaping quotes for sqlite3

Tags: shell, sqlite, applescript

I want to query a column that has spaces in its name. The shell script is:

```
select "Column 1" from aTable;
```

Maybe it is late, but I am having a hard time escaping the Applescript:

```
set xxx to do shell script "sqlite3 ~/Documents/Databases/test.db \"select \"Address 1\" from aTable limit 10; \""
```

Comment: Is it too late to try to convince you to use real SQLite bindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes around your SQL:

```
set xxx to do shell script "sqlite3 ~/Documents/Databases/test.db 'select \"Address 1\" from aTable limit 10; '"
```

Or if you want to beat yourself up, keep using double quotes everywhere and add more escaping:

```
set xxx to do shell script "sqlite3 ~/Documents/Databases/test.db \"select \\\"Address 1\\\" from aTable limit 10; \""
```

You need three because you have to escape the escapes to get an escaped double quote down to the shell. Ick.

Or better, use a native AppleScript SQLite interface, a couple minutes of googling should find you something nicer than the above nested quote madness.

Comment: Right on all three accounts, Thank you.